# page layout using geometry and minipage

Tags: graphics, minipage

[image]

I am needing to make a page layout that has these dimensions, am thinking the geometry package and minipage? unsure - am new to this so if anyone is able to help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You have to write only one page or all the pages should be like that? And the boxes should be framed?

Comment: just the first page like that